# Android paypal capture and send specified details to the backend

Tags: android, paypal

I currently implementing android paypal into my app, right now i'm able to send the paymentId and the approval on to my backend, but how do i send the `amount` to my backend? Below is my json response.

```
{
 "amount": "0.5",
 "currency_code": "MYR",
 "short_description": "Credit Top-up",
 "intent": "sale"
}

{
 "client": {
 "environment": "sandbox",
 "paypal_sdk_version": "2.15.3",
 "platform": "Android",
 "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK"
 },
 "response": {
 "create_time": "2017-08-20T10:25:11Z",
 "id": "PAY-5MU049465A842625GLGMWG6Y",
 "intent": "sale",
 "state": "approved"
 },
 "response_type": "payment"
}
```

I can capture and send the `id` and `state` into my backend, but i couldn't capture the `amount`, so how do i able to capture it? Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Paypal documentation you will get response like below:-  [for more information go to Paypal reference doc](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/)

```
{
      "client":{
        "environment":"sandbox",
        "paypal_sdk_version":"2.0.0",
        "platform":"iOS",
        "product_name":"PayPal iOS SDK;"
      },
      "response":{
        "create_time":"2014-02-12T22:29:49Z",
        "id":"PAY-564191241M8701234KL57LXI",
        "intent":"sale",
        "state":"approved"
      },
      "response_type":"payment"
    }
```

You won't get amount on response so you can get the amount value from Client side and send it to your own server to verify the payment.(You have already the amount value which is passed to PAYPAL).

Comment: Ok now i can send the amount to my server. Right now how do i bind this `amount` to my `login` users, which mean whenever a certain user login, and use this paypal system, it will credit the amount of that user, how can i do that?

Comment: I am not getting what you actually want to do?

Comment: My android app can login and register, and any user can use the paypal feature but have a slight problem. When i login for certain user and use the paypal, how does the `amount` can be credited to the user? Right now when i use the paypal, it doesn't top-up for that user. I'm sorry for my english, hope you can understand.

Comment: Create a new question and ask your problem over there. And first of all tell us what the App does. and what you want to do.

Comment: here is the link [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45784545/android-paypal-send-payment-for-login-user)