# Android paypal send payment for login user

Tags: php, android, paypal

I would like to ask is it possible to send the payment for login-ed user using paypal? My android app is a simple booking movie ticket system. I implement the paypal feature to top-up the current user balance. Below is my php table screenshot.

[User account table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFVcN.png)

[Paypal verification table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsPKj.png)

So right now, when i login the user `abc`, and i top-up using paypal. After the payment is done, the payment suppose to send to the user `abc` but it would not send, so what should i do in order to send the payment to the user? Furthermore, how do i able get the `Acc_ID` from `user account table` and update in `paypal verification table`, mean that when i click the `Acc_ID 1` in `user account table` it will link to `paypal verification table`. As you can see that the `Acc_ID` in `paypal verification table` are `0`, i do not know how to achieve that.

In-case if anyone want to see my php code, here it is or if you want my java code i can update as well. Can someone please help, i will be very appreciated!

**token.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'save.php';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST)){
$payment_id = $_POST['PAYMENT_ID'];
$state = $_POST['STATE'];
$amount = $_POST['AMOUNT'];

$saveObject = new Save();
$saveObject->savePaymentDetail($payment_id, $state, $amount);
}
?>
```

**save.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
class Save{
private $db;
public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new DbConnect();
}
public function savePaymentDetail($payment_id, $state, $amount){
    $query = "INSERT INTO paypal_verification(payment_id, state, amount) VALUES ('$payment_id', '$state', '$amount')";
    $inserted = mysqli_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);

    if($inserted == 1){
        $json = Array('success' => '1');
    }else{
        $json = Array('success' => '0');
    }
    mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
    echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
}
?>
```

**Working**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO paypal_verification (acc_id, payment_id, state, amount) 
              SELECT acc_id, '$payment_id', '$state', '$amount' FROM account_details WHERE Username='abc'";
```

**Not Working**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO paypal_verification (acc_id, payment_id, state, amount) 
              SELECT acc_id, '$payment_id', '$state', '$amount' FROM account_details WHERE Username='$Username'";
```

Comment: Your code shouldn't work.  Why are you throwing post data in your insert,  then on the next line binding the values.  You are cancelling and demolishing the effect of prepared statements.  You really need to read the manual..

Comment: But i can still send the payment id into the database. Do you have a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to get it working but is only partially, meaning that right now i can update my `user account` table `balance` from `paypal_verification` `amount` and can set the `acc_id` as well, i'm not sure how do i explain well but i can show the picture of the updated mysql table and also the php code.

[User account table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTy0K.png)

[paypal_verification table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPyp0.png)

**php file**

```
<?php
include_once 'db.php';
class Save{

private $db;
public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new DbConnect();
}
public function savePaymentDetail($payment_id, $state, $amount){
    $query = "INSERT INTO paypal_verification (acc_id, payment_id, state, amount) 
              SELECT acc_id, '$payment_id', '$state', '$amount' FROM account_details WHERE account_details.Acc_ID=account_details.Acc_ID;";

    $amount = $amount + amount;

    $query .= "UPDATE account_details SET account_details.Acc_Balance = (SELECT SUM(paypal_verification.amount) 
               FROM paypal_verification WHERE account_details.Acc_ID = paypal_verification.Acc_ID)
               WHERE account_details.Acc_ID=account_details.Acc_ID";


    $inserted = mysqli_multi_query($this->db->getDb(), $query);

    if($inserted == 1){
        $json = Array('success' => '1');
    }else{
        $json = Array('success' => '0');
    }
    mysqli_close($this->db->getDb());
    echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    echo $query;
}

}
?>
```

Right now when i pay, it will pay for both users. How do i specifically pay just for the login-ed user from my android app?

**How to know that this paypal is pay for a specific user?**

Answer (score 1):

If the payment is successful like here

```
$json = Array('success' => '1');
```

then you need to update User Account Table like this

1. get the current balance from the user table
2. add the new amount to current balance and update the user row.

Comment: How do i able to get the current balance from the user table? Should i make a get query inside the `save.php` or in the `token.php`?

Comment: In which php file to make the query?

Comment: Hi! Right now i'm making just the `paypal_verification` table to have those `Acc_ID`, the `Acc_ID` is working to get the id from `user_table` but it's just when i set the `Username='abc' `, if i set to `Username='$Username' ` it would not work anymore. Please tell me how can i fix it?